# If an optimization can be made on the if algorithm

Tags: javascript

i have the following state:

```
state = {
    profile: {
      name: { value: '', isRequired: true, hasError: false, order: 1 },
      industry: { value: '', isRequired: false, hasError: false, order: 2 },
      address: { value: '', isRequired: false, hasError: false, order: 3 },
      crn: { value: '', isRequired: true, hasError: false, order: 4 },
      website: { value: '', isRequired: false, hasError: false, order: 5 },
      employeesNbr: { value: '', isRequired: true, hasError: false, order: 6 },
      phoneNumber: { value: '', isRequired: true, hasError: false, order: 7 },
      userRole: { value: '', isRequired: true, hasError: false, order: 8 },
      personCheck: {
        value: false,
        isRequired: true,
        hasError: false,
        order: 9,
      },
    },
    showModal: {
      modal: { error: false },
    },
  };
```

And I have the following section of a submit handler

```
if (
        !profile.name.hasError &&
        !profile.crn.hasError &&
        !profile.employeesNbr.hasError &&
        !profile.phoneNumber.hasError &&
        !profile.userRole.hasError &&
        profile.personCheck.hasError
      ) {
        showModal.modal.error = true;
      }
```

What ways can I use to enhance the if statement?
Thank you

Comment: Isn't the condition backwards? If none of the `hasError` flags are true, shouldn't it set `error = false`?

Comment: Why do you invert all the `hasError` flags except `personCheck`?

Comment: @Barmar it seems that only the last thing has an error, the others don't. But I really don't think that's correct, either.

Comment: The thing is this is an extra check, i am sending the showmodal as a prop to open up a modal only and only if all the other fields dont have an error except for person check

Comment: What do you mean by "enhance"?

Comment: I mean for the same logic to be applicable with less number of code, and maybe have an effect on speed also. Note the logic in terms of result i am getting is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following way it would be optimized since as soon as one of the `profile.*` props has `hasError` to `true` would "returns" (due the **or** instead of **and**): the **and** (`&&`) needs to evaluate all the conditions where the **or** `||` it stops as soon as one is `true`.

You can also probably remove the `if` statement:

```
showModal.modal.error = profile.personCheck.hasError && !(
                          profile.name.hasError ||
                          profile.crn.hasError ||
                          profile.employeesNbr.hasError ||
                          profile.phoneNumber.hasError ||
                          profile.userRole.hasError)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you like it better that way?

```
if (
        !(profile.name.hasError ||
        profile.crn.hasError ||
        profile.employeesNbr.hasError ||
        profile.phoneNumber.hasError ||
        profile.userRole.hasError) &&
        profile.personCheck.hasError
      ) {
        showModal.modal.error = true;
      }
```

or if you prefer something more fancy:

```
if (
    (Object.entries(state.profile)
        .filter(prop => prop[1].hasError).length === 1) && // there is exactly one error
    state.profile.personCheck.hasError // personCheck has error
)
```

Comment: I hate it. I don't like going back and forth to find out what the NOT affects. I find OP's version more readable.

Comment: I like it better -- positive tests are usually easier to understand than negatives. deMorgan's Law makes it easy to rewrite.

Comment: It could work also but harder to read maybe like @VLAZ pointed out

Answer (score 0):

It would be easy to simplify it into a loop if you were doing the same check for all properties in the profile. Doing a different check for `personCheck` makes it hard to reduce it like that.

You can use an array for all the properties that you want the same check on.

```
if (profile.personCheck.hasError && 
    ["name", "crn", "employeesNbr", "phoneNumber", "userRole"].every(prop => !profile[prop].hasError)) {
    showModal.modal.error = true;
}
```